# Horizontal alignment of tikz floats in tufte margins

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, margins, tufte, cutwin

I try to make the symmetrical floats on verso and recto pages of tufte-class book. This diagram shows what I want to achieve and it also shows the discrepancy: 
[image]

(the first page is not important). The question is: how to make the float to be "right aligned", to be aligned with its right side to be symmetrical to its recto counterpart. The captions must stay where they are - on the margins.

This is MWE.

```
\documentclass[twoside,symmetric,notoc,justified]{tufte-book}%

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pgf,caption,calc}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{cutwin}
\usetkzobj{all}


\geometry{
  %showframe,%Показывает рамки
  paperwidth=145mm,
  paperheight=215mm,
  inner=16mm,
  outer=10mm,
  top=10mm,
  bottom=40mm,
  marginparsep=3mm,
  marginparwidth=40mm,
  includemp,
  includehead,
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]


\opencutleft
\begin{shapedcutout}{2}{16}{0.90\textwidth, 0.79\textwidth,0.7\textwidth, 0.65\textwidth,0.61\textwidth, 0.6\textwidth, 0.55\textwidth, 0.55\textwidth, 0.55\textwidth, 0.55\textwidth, 0.6\textwidth,0.61\textwidth, 0.65\textwidth,0.7\textwidth, 0.79\textwidth,0.90\textwidth}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{shapedcutout}

\begin{marginfigure}[-25.5cm]
{\caption{This is caption}\label{fig:label}}
{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\tkzInit[xmin=-0.5, xmax=7, ymin=-5, ymax=2.5]
\tkzClip
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/A, 2.5/2/B, 6/0/C}
\tkzCircumCenter(A,B,C)\tkzGetPoint{O}
\tkzDrawCircle(O,A)
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{marginfigure}


\opencutright
\begin{shapedcutout}{2}{16}{0.90\textwidth, 0.79\textwidth,0.7\textwidth, 0.65\textwidth,0.61\textwidth, 0.6\textwidth, 0.55\textwidth, 0.55\textwidth, 0.55\textwidth, 0.55\textwidth, 0.6\textwidth,0.61\textwidth, 0.65\textwidth,0.7\textwidth, 0.79\textwidth,0.90\textwidth}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{shapedcutout}

\begin{marginfigure}[-25.5cm]
{\caption{This is caption}\label{fig:label1}}
{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\tkzInit[xmin=-0.5, xmax=7, ymin=-5, ymax=2.5]
\tkzClip
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/A, 2.5/2/B, 6/0/C}
\tkzCircumCenter(A,B,C)\tkzGetPoint{O}
\tkzDrawCircle(O,A)
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{marginfigure}



\end{document}
```

Comment: You could adjust it by hand by adding `\hspace*{-3cm}` before the second `\begin{tikzpicture}`, but this is certainly not satisfactory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how it worked for me. But I still welcome other solutions.
The trick is to start the second tikzpicture like this:

```
\rightline{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
```

This is the full code:

```
\documentclass[twoside,symmetric,notoc,justified]{tufte-book}%

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pgf,caption,calc}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{cutwin}
\usetkzobj{all}


\geometry{
  %showframe,%Показывает рамки
  paperwidth=145mm,
  paperheight=215mm,
  inner=16mm,
  outer=10mm,
  top=10mm,
  bottom=40mm,
  marginparsep=3mm,
  marginparwidth=40mm,
  includemp,
  includehead,
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]


\opencutleft
\begin{shapedcutout}{2}{16}{0.90\textwidth, 0.79\textwidth,0.7\textwidth, 0.65\textwidth,0.61\textwidth, 0.6\textwidth, 0.55\textwidth, 0.55\textwidth, 0.55\textwidth, 0.55\textwidth, 0.6\textwidth,0.61\textwidth, 0.65\textwidth,0.7\textwidth, 0.79\textwidth,0.90\textwidth}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{shapedcutout}

\begin{marginfigure}[-25.5cm]
{\caption{This is caption}\label{fig:label}}
{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\tkzInit[xmin=-0.5, xmax=7, ymin=-5, ymax=2.5]
\tkzClip
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/A, 2.5/2/B, 6/0/C}
\tkzCircumCenter(A,B,C)\tkzGetPoint{O}
\tkzDrawCircle(O,A)
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{marginfigure}


\opencutright
\begin{shapedcutout}{2}{16}{0.90\textwidth, 0.79\textwidth,0.7\textwidth, 0.65\textwidth,0.61\textwidth, 0.6\textwidth, 0.55\textwidth, 0.55\textwidth, 0.55\textwidth, 0.55\textwidth, 0.6\textwidth,0.61\textwidth, 0.65\textwidth,0.7\textwidth, 0.79\textwidth,0.90\textwidth}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{shapedcutout}

\begin{marginfigure}[-25.5cm]
{\caption{This is caption}\label{fig:label1}}
\rightline{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\tkzInit[xmin=-0.5, xmax=7, ymin=-5, ymax=2.5]
\tkzClip
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/A, 2.5/2/B, 6/0/C}
\tkzCircumCenter(A,B,C)\tkzGetPoint{O}
\tkzDrawCircle(O,A)
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{marginfigure}
\end{document}
```

This is the output:
[image]
Again, I am not sure that this is the best solution, but it aligns the picture exactly.

```
\hspace*{-3cm}
```

also works, but requires a manual adjustment.