# TikZ picture as margin figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, margins, sidenotes

**Question:**
I want to put a `tikzpicture` as a margin figure. I have a minimal version with the `sidenotes` package. However, it wouldn't work with the `tikzpicture` I want to have there.

**Example with sidenotes package:**
[image]

**MWE with sidenotes package:**

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{sidenotes}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{marginfigure}%
\includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{marginfigure}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

**Problem:**
I want to insert a `tikzpicture` in the margin. It looks like this:
[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\firstcircle{(0,0) circle (1.5cm)}
    \def\secondcircle{(0:0.5cm) circle (0.8cm)}
    
    \colorlet{circle edge}{red!50}
    \colorlet{circle area}{red!20}
    
    \tikzset{filled/.style={fill=circle area, draw=circle edge, thick},
        outline/.style={draw=circle edge, thick}}
    
    \setlength{\parskip}{5mm}
    \begin{scope}
    \clip \firstcircle;
    \fill[filled] \secondcircle;
    \end{scope}
    \draw[outline] \firstcircle node [xshift=-20pt] {$M_2$};
    \draw[outline] \secondcircle node {$M_1$};
    \node[anchor=south] at (current bounding box.north) {$M_1 \subsetneq M_2$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The problem is that the document wouldn't compile, but I don't know why. I did the following:

```
\begin{marginfigure}%
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
...
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{marginfigure}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What happens if you remove `\begin{figure}` and `\end{figure}` from within your `marginfigure` environment?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135286/using-marginfigure-command  --- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/411084/horizontal-alignment-of-tikz-floats-in-tufte-margins

Comment: @cmhughes Thank you, it worked... I tried it before but it didn't work, I must have done something else wrong back then.

Comment: @NilsK great! perhaps you could self-answer your question with *full* details of how you fixed it, including a complete, minimal example :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @cmhughes the question could be answered. The solution is to remove the figure environment. I provide the following MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{sidenotes}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes,backgrounds,fit}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{marginfigure}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\firstcircle{(0,0) circle (1.5cm)}
    \def\secondcircle{(0:0.5cm) circle (0.8cm)}
    
    \colorlet{circle edge}{red!50}
    \colorlet{circle area}{red!20}
    
    \tikzset{filled/.style={fill=circle area, draw=circle edge, thick},
        outline/.style={draw=circle edge, thick}}
    
    \setlength{\parskip}{5mm}
    \begin{scope}
    \clip \firstcircle;
    \fill[filled] \secondcircle;
    \end{scope}
    \draw[outline] \firstcircle node [xshift=-20pt] {$M_2$};
    \draw[outline] \secondcircle node {$M_1$};
    \node[anchor=south] at (current bounding box.north) {$M_1 \subsetneq M_2$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{marginfigure}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```